# Firebase setup after upgrading to Flutter 3.19.0 (Host platform returned null value for non-null return value)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle

I am upgrading Flutter to 3.19.0 and I am having problem with Android setup. According to Flutter's [breaking changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply), the Android setup should look different now. I think I followed all the instructions and have the following gradle files:

android/settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
}

include ":app"
```

android/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('dev.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def prodKeystoreProperties = new Properties()
def prodKeystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('....properties')
if (prodKeystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    prodKeystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(prodKeystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            // Filter for architectures supported by Flutter.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    testOptions {
        execution "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.2"
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the app, the Firebase package doesn't initialize properly with error:

> PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null).

And the app stays stuck at splash screen.

I've seen many solutions to that problem but they use old `buildscript` approach to android dependencies, I haven't found any solution to this using the new approach.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to downgrade from 4.4.0 to `4.3.15` or `4.3.8`

`id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false`